# Proof help: the periodic sets in R form a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

I have been given the following as an exercise in my measure theory class.

> Show that the periodic sets of $\Bbb R$ form a σ-algebra; that is, let $\mathfrak B$ be the
>   class of sets $\mathfrak A$ with the property that x ∈ $\mathfrak A$ implies x ± n ∈ $\mathfrak A$ for all
>   natural numbers n. Then $\mathfrak B$ is a σ-algebra.

I have so far proved easily that $ \varnothing$ is contained in $\mathfrak B$, and that if A,B are in $\mathfrak B$ then A $\cup$ B is also in $\mathfrak B$

For some reason, I am struggling to prove that complements **NOW SOLVED** and countable unions hold. Please can I have some help **WITH COUNTABLE UNIONS**?

I am assuming that A $\in$ $\mathfrak B$. And so for natural n, if x $\in$ A then x $\pm$ n $\in$ A. Take y $\in$ $A^c$. Then either y $\pm$ n $\in$ A or y $\pm$ n $\in$ $A^c$.

Obviously, if in the latter case, we are done. But I am unsure of how to proceed to show that the first case is not possible.

Comment: the first case is not possible since $y \pm n \in A$ implies $ y = y \pm n \mp n \in A$ (by the periodicity of $A$), which is a contradiction since $y$ is taken from the complementer.

Comment: @relep ah yes! That was definitely a silly think to miss, thank you.

Comment: how did you show $A, B \in \mathfrak{B}$ implies $A \cup B \in \mathfrak{B}$? are you sure you can't generalize that proof to show that $\mathfrak{B}$ is in fact closed under taking an union of arbitrarily many sets?

Comment: @relep Hold on, I will write what I currently have down and attach it to the question! :) I have been thinking of attempting that.

Comment: @relep wont let me upload a photo, so: I have taken A,B $\in$ $\mathfrak B$, then divided this into cases: A,B are disjoint, or A $\subset$ B. If one is a subset of the other, then A $\cup$ B is just A (or B) and we're done.

Comment: If A $\cap$ B = $\varnothing$ then A $\cup$ B contains x s.t x $\pm$ n $\in$ A or x $\pm$ n $\in$ B which is the same as x $\pm$ n $\in$ A $\cup$ B. 

MESSY I KNOW. :/

Comment: @relep I have solved the question now, differently to how I was originally trying to! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, a "periodic set" looks like this: take some subset of $[0, 1)$, and then copy/paste it along the entire real line. So there's a bijection between $\mathfrak B$ and subsets of $[0, 1)$. Where $A$ is a subset of $[0, 1)$, we'll write $B_A$ for the corresponding periodic set.

The complement of $B_A$ is $B_{A'}$ for some $A'$. Can you guess what $A'$ is?

Now, given a sequence of subsets $(A_i)$, can you find a $C$ such that $\bigcup B_{A_i}=B_C$?

Comment: [0,1) \ A? I'm not really sure of the second question, can you explain a bit more in detail? Sorry :/

Comment: @mathcomp It's simply $\bigcup A_i$.

Comment: Thank you! Its nice to see a different perspective on things! I solved it differently in the end, but this has definitely aided my understanding!